# database using foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

please excuse me if i'm doing things wrong, as I am new to this forum.. I am trying to figure out what columns to have for foreign keys... My teacher redid my database and i can't understand what to do. Here is my ERD: http://s1.postimg.org/3l2j6rh4v/Picture.png

I have looked up tutorials but I can't seem to find out how to use them..

Here is my MySQL code:

```
DROP TABLE PaymentType;
DROP TABLE ProjectType;
DROP TABLE Projects;
DROP TABLE Payment;
DROP TABLE Customer;
CREATE TABLE Customer
(
Customer_ID            varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
FName                  varchar(15)     NOT NULL,
LName                  varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
CustAddress            varchar(20)     NOT NULL,
CustCity               varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
CustState              varchar(20),
CustZip                char(5),
CustBal                numeric(7,2)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Customer_ID)
);
CREATE TABLE Payment
(
Payment_ID             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
PaymentType            varchar(15),
Date                   date            NOT NULL,
AmntPaid               numeric(7,2)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Projects
(
Project_ID             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
ProjectType            varchar(30)     NOT NULL,
LaborHrs               char(3)         NOT NULL,
Date                   date            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ProjectType
(
Project_ID             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
ProjectDesc             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Project_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PaymentType
(
Payment_ID             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
PaymentDesc             varchar(100)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Payment_ID)
);
```

Hopefully I didn't do anything wrong, thanks!

Comment: you should add "if exists" to your "drop table" commands. (eg. "DROP TABLE PaymentType IF EXISTS;") - this will prevent errors if the tables didn't exist in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should change your types for the id columns. Using varchar as id column should be avoided, as this will just blow off the performance (+ some other problems which might occur). Using any type of int (int, tinyint,..) would be much better.

2) The table "ProjectType" should have a column "ProjectType_ID" instead of "Project_ID" - same goes for the PaymentType ("PaymentType_ID").

3) Rename the fields in "Project" and "Payment" table as well.

4) The code for foreign-keys will look like:

```
ALTER TABLE Project
ADD CONSTRAINT Project_ProjectType
FOREIGN KEY (ProjectType_ID)
REFERENCES ProjectType(ProjectType_ID);
```

Do the same with Payment table.

**Important: add "alter table"-command to the end of your sql file, so all tables are created**
**Important: your database schema should be innodb, or any other schema which supports foreign-keys (MyIsam does NOT support foreign-keys)**

5) For the relation between Customer and Projects you will need an extra table (so one project can have multiple users | might be a change to your erd). A cross-relation table (called something Like CustomerProject) with fields "Project_ID" and "Customer_ID". Then add a foreign-key to the project table and add a foreign-key to customer table. (extra points for adding a unique key to "Project_ID" + "Customer_ID")

For the payment and user, just add a "Customer_ID" field in "Payment" table and add a foreign-key as explained in #4.

(offtopic): your naming convention is a bit wierd. Mixing underscore and camelcase should be avoided. You can just stick to camelcase - even for your id fields - but this is just a personal opinion